# How to configure world server Idiom Process Monitor service

Tags: sdl-tridion, worldserver

Due to some windows server patching related issues, we create new Windows ISO image and restored to existing VM. after restore OS Disk,we are unable to find "Idiom process Monitor service" in services list.
if we run "idiomrunw.exe" file, its throwing error as below.
[image]
if we run "Startup.bat" file, our website is running but need to setup idiom process monitor service as earliest. can you please provide steps to configure the Automatic "Idiom process service".

world server version : 11.4.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like there might be an issue with the "**Idiom Process Monitor service**" on your Windows Server after restoring the OS disk. Here are some steps you can take to troubleshoot and potentially resolve the issue:

**1. Check Service Status:**

- Open the Services console by typing services.msc in the Run dialog (Win + R) and press Enter.
- Look for the "Idiom Process Monitor service" in the list and check its status. Ensure that it's set to "Automatic" or "Manual" and is started. If it's not present, there might be an issue with the installation.

**2. Reinstall Idiom Process Monitor:**

- If the service is not present or not working correctly, you might need to reinstall the Idiom Process Monitor. Obtain the installation package or setup file for Idiom Process Monitor and run the installation process again.

Refer to Documentation for [Deploying WorldServer through Tomcat (on Windows)](https://docs.rws.com/686723/36790/sdl-worldserver-11-4-user-documentation/deploying-------------worldserver-through-tomcat--on-windows-)

**3. Check Event Viewer:**

- Open the Event Viewer (**eventvwr.msc**) and check the Windows logs, especially the System and Application logs, for any errors related to the Idiom Process Monitor service. This might provide more details on why the service is not starting.

**4. Verify Dependencies:**

- Some services depend on other services or components. Check if the Idiom Process Monitor service has any dependencies and ensure that those services are running.

**5. Check File Integrity:**

- Verify the integrity of the Idiom Process Monitor files. Ensure that the "idiomrunw.exe" file is not corrupted. You may want to compare it with a known good version.

**6. Contact Support:**

- If the issue persists and you are unable to resolve it, consider reaching out to the support or documentation for Idiom Process Monitor. They might have specific steps or solutions for the problem you are facing.

Remember to back up important data and configurations before making any changes to your system. If you are not familiar with these troubleshooting steps or if the issue persists, consider involving your IT support team or seeking assistance from the RWS or RWS Partners.